# Using 1 Object To Represent 2 Models

Tags: php, oop, yii

We are building a core shopping cart that our company will use as a foundation for multiple shopping carts we will build. These are highly specialized, so different product types will require their own tables of data.

For instance, for a cart that sells labels...

**product** - `id | type_id | created`

**label** - `id | product_id | x | y | z`

We're struggling with how to structure our objects.  We'd like to programmatically only interact with the *Label* class and have the data be "split" so to speak between the two tables. One idea we tossed around was creating a *view* to use for querying and then just overwriting the object's `save()` method to actually interact with each table's setters/save functionality.

Has anyone accomplished this or at least faced a similar challenge?

**Update:** Of course this begs the question... is there a scenario where both tables might have the same column name?  And if so, how to handle it.

Comment: i'm just guessing, maybe another example cart(_tables_) will give more clarity to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use name/value pair for specialized columns. With "name" part consistent with column names, you can have generalized setter/getter.

Answer (score 0):

Product is related table, so you can interact with it via relation, for instance `$labelModel->product`. So you have model for each table, as yii suggest. And you can interact only with `Label` model if you place your functionality at `beforeSave()`, `afterSave()` and other methods.